# Constant disconnects due to channels going stale for no reason

Tags: google-app-engine

Ever since the latest release a few days ago, our users are constantly being disconnected due to channel tokens going stale with minutes of being created. Our tokens are set to last for 5 hours, but we're lucky if they last for 5-10 minutes and we cannot even reconnect with a new channel token when the channel closes until the user refreshes.

A Javascript error triggers the beginning of it. It looks like this:

NetworkError: 400 Unknown SID - http://89.talkgadget.google.com/talkgadget/dch/bind?VER=8&clid=C9C2EFC06C7C5163&gsessionid&prop=data&token=AHRlWrrWl611ZMMDw8Apgi5vdYuS9UslofxEiJI47-2n4rkPgmuu1z0AN-UNQcyNEvhck-AYAMSLPru8Aumooz62hYNNbLTbi1a3lTSAzGEyj6TsXZirJYE&RID=rpc&SID=BEBDEFDA92C6A9F7&CI=0&AID=54&TYPE=xmlhttp&zx=gsjg8mb1i987&t=1

Then, in Firefox Firebug, the console gets spammed infinitely with

channel name mismatch; message ignored

Until a refresh occurs.

Our site is a real-time interactive site with chat. Our users are sending us emails upset that they keep getting disconnected. They're leaving the site. This is costing us not only goodwill with our user base, but also money and we are powerless to do anything because the bug is with Google App Engine.

Please fix this or rollback to the previous build immediately until you figure this out. The latest build is broken.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't been able to reproduce this but I'm still looking at it. In the meantime: if you explicitly call socket.close() after receiving the error, can you then create a new Channel object and reconnect? If that doesn't work, you could even try manually removing the element with id "wcs-iframe" itself from the DOM. You should be able to use the original token when doing this instead of fetching a new token.

Comment: Thank you. This mitigates the issue as our users can now be reconnected.

However, since we have a finite number of channels available to us each day, requesting channel tokens that expire in 5 hours and having them go stale 5 minutes later to be replaced by another 5 hour token that goes stale a few minutes later is not going to last long for us. I appreciate you looking into this issue! :)

Comment: You should be able to re-use the initial token for the whole 5 hours -- it isn't expiring; something else is causing a disconnect. If you cache the token value on the client side you should be able to use it again until you get a token timed-out error.

Comment: How do I tell the difference between a token that is prematurely expiring from a token that has actually expired? Are you suggesting that I should do a connection retry and if it fails the second time then I know it's actually expired and should get a new token? All this is doing is mitigating the underlying issue which was introduced in the last update to GAE. These tokens shouldn't be prematurely expiring.

Comment: I don't think the token is actually timing out. When it does, you should get an onerror callback with an error object whose code property is set to 401 and whose description property is set to "Token+timed+out." This should be followed by an onclose callback.

These unknown SID errors may trigger the onerror callback -- and you may stop receiving messages, though I haven't caught this "in the wild" to know. But you should get a different error in your onerror handler, and I wouldn't expect onclose to be called.

Comment: @MoisheLettvin Hello, I am also using google app engine and compute engine for our app. I am using python client for implementing the Channel API using this code https://bitbucket.org/lohre/gae_channel/overview/ . But I am getting same error of Unknown SID but not able to solve it in python. Can you please guide me how can i get rid of this. Many Thanks